# I'm not sure if I'm allowed to do this, but I need help with my Stack Overflow account

Tags: bug, post-ban

I recently got this message when I tried to ask a question:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.

I am very sorry for what I've done. I think it's because I removed a question. I've edited the post and put the answer back. The reason why I edited the post:

```
I don't want people to read my code.
```

My question is, is there a way to get unbanned? I promise I won't remove the code again!
Please do not dislike/not a question or whatever you guys do.

Comment: The ban is applied when there is more than *one* problem. Read the post linked carefully, you'll have to do more than fix just one question.

Comment: 3 out of 5 questions were downvoted. 3 out of 5 were closed. That combined has caused the ban. Not a single event. Please read the duplicate in full. It contains all the information we can give you.

Comment: okay, but is there a possible to get unbaned?

Comment: Read the duplicate. The ban is automatic and so is lifting it. Nobody can do that for you. So putting "please ask them to unban me" in your profile won't achieve anything.

Comment: You are not in trial; you are not in jail. Sorry is not relevant. Improve your existing questions if possible and if not start posting new answers. Enough upvotes on either of those and the ban should be lifted automatically. From the little I saw you are treating Stack Overflow as a personal help forum; well, it's not.